# How do I stop AVG from flagging and deleting bat files?

Tags: windows, avg

AVG insists on blocking bat files that all our operators use.
The files are on a network drive with shortcuts on their desktop.
This gives us complete control of which version gets loaded without needing to touch every machine.
About 5 or 10% of the time, AVG flags the file as "suspicious" and deletes it for everyone.
Then it sends me an email about what a good boy it has been, expecting approval.

```
Threat Type: Suspicious    
File path: I:\Load Order System.bat    
Detected by: Behavior Shield

A threat has been found by Behavior Shield and has been resolved automatically.
```

When I'm on their machine testing something and it happens to me, I can add an exception for that bat file for that machine.

Seems like there should be a system-wide solution but I can't find it.

Thanks, Brad.

Answer (score 0):

From the AVG console, go to Policies, click on the name of the current "in use" policy, Exclusions.

Further details here:
https://businesshelp.avg.com/Content/Products/AVG_Management_Consoles/ConfiguringSettingsandPolicies/ConfiguringStandardAntivirusExclusions.htm?Highlight=exclusions